# How to speed up space partitioning in postgis?

Tags: postgis, topology, optimization

I've a bunch of overlapping polygons and I'm trying to partition the space to avoid having overlapping ones. I think my problem is fairly simple.
Using some ESRI product and http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=16700 my co-worker computed it in 48s.

I'm trying to do it with postgis using http://s3.opengeo.org/postgis-power.pdf#page=24 (guessing the details, using http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiSimplifyPreserveTopology as inspiration) but it's so slow that I can't do it with more than 10 polys (I've got 800 of them to split). The slow part is the ST_Union, I tried various things, but none where successful, here is the current state of affairs :

```
select geom from
(select st_linemerge(st_union(geom)) as geom from
    (select st_exteriorring((st_dumprings((st_dump(t.geom)).geom)).geom) as geom from
        (SELECT geometry AS geom, id
               FROM tt
              WHERE campaign_id = 204
              ORDER BY id limit 200) t) t2) t3
```

this has been computing for 26 min (the linemerge() is actually not ). The polys are MultiPolygons in case the st_dump bugs you.

Do you have any tip ? The st_union() of the linework is the very slow part.

Thanks,

Nico.

PS: 
here are some numbers : 852 multipolygons, leading to 14880 polygons, leading to 21467 linestrings totaling 315513 vertices.

Comment: If no-one answers you may wish to try the postGIS mailing list.

Comment: I'm not really fan of mailing lists, moreover, it might also be an GEOS problem, who might complain about JTS, well, I prefer keeping the problem open.

Comment: by collecting the linework and doing an union with an empty geometry, I can do it in 800s : st_union(st_collect(geom), st_setsrid(geomfromtext('POINT EMPTY'), 900913)) that's almost 20 times slower than the ESRI stuff.

Comment: from memory, try drop st_union from st_linemerge(st_union...) if it helps

Answer (score 3):

This answer may not help @nraynaud directly, but hopefully will shed some light on the subject.

There is a similar issue in spatiaLite < 4.0 due an issue with GEOS.  See [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=&hl=en#!topic/spatialite-users/FTO_cmLCfpE) for a discussion of the issue.

The workaround is to replace the ST_Union() function with ST_UnaryUnion(ST_Collect( )).  Unfortunately, ST_UnaryUnion is not available until postGIS 2.0 (as far as I can tell.)

Answer (score 1):

Which version of PostGIS are you using?  Unioning is much slower if you are using PostGIS < 1.4 or GEOS < 3.2.  Much faster union was introduced in 1.4, but also requires GEOS 3.2+.  So first if you are using lower than 1.4, I'd upgrade to at least 1.5.

```
SELECT postgis_full_version();
```

To check.

Also is your intention to keep the original edges of the polygons.  If you just want to dissolve overlapping areas,

```
SELECT ST_Union(geom) FROM tt WHERE campaign_id = 204;
```

Would do the trick.

Comment: hello, here is the result : "POSTGIS="1.5.3" GEOS="3.3.2-CAPI-1.7.2" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" LIBXML="2.7.3" USE_STATS". I could not find any relevant addition to union in GEOS recently. I found one speedup in polygon unions, but I'm not merging polygons, and this speedup seems controversial. I absolutely don't want do union my polygons as I have to add values for overlapping polygons.